# Menu in UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uipopovercontroller

Is there an easy way to achieve a menu like this? Or do I have to build it with a popoverViewController and several UIButtons by myself?

Thanks a lot!

[image: Menu]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to use a `UIActionSheet` and use the following method to present it:

```
- (void)showFromBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)item animated:(BOOL)animated
```

I did not try it out, but it looks promising from the docs.

This method might also have the same effect:

```
- (void)showFromRect:(CGRect)rect inView:(UIView *)view animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Comment: What I have now is that the popover shows in the middle of the screen. So I implemented the method:

`- (void)showFromBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)item animated:(BOOL)animated`

This:

`UIBarButtonItem *showMenuButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Menü" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showMenu:self:YES)];`

... gives an error. I know that it's wrong but what is the right way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Probably your selector was not well formed. I usually use a simple selector with one colon that expects the sender as the only param.

Comment: Yes, so did I. After all I defined my `UIBarButtonItem` globally.

Comment: This should not be necessary if all you only need a reference to it in order to present the action sheet. You can simply use a method `- (void)showMenuFromBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)item` and then create the bar button like this: `[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Menü" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showMenuFromBarButtonItem:)];`

Answer (score 0):

You're right, use `UIPopoverController`, and add you're own content. Useful [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1056/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uipopovercontroller-tutorial).

Comment: Yes, I did that but I don't want these customizations ... Thanks anyway.